# Kendo UI - VueJS Package download

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui

Currently, we have purchased Dev Craft Complete from the Telerik Site:
https://www.telerik.com/purchase/kendo-ui.

Unfortunately, we aren't able to trace files related to Kendo with Vue in the package downloaded from Telerik site, as this is required for Project.

Appreciate your help in guiding us through the detailed step implementation.

Awaiting your response.

Thanks,
Akshata

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo files related to Vue are distributed through npm. You can check the demos for the exact source as this one for example - https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/.